# pointer-events not changing properly from none to auto on iOS

Tags: javascript, html, ios, google-chrome, pointer-events

I am a lot new to html, javascript and coding in general.

Initially I have a text which is hidden until button is pressed, after button is pressed text appears and is clickable (opens another tab with a specific link).

In page I have this text as:

```
<p class="card-descr text-itx disabled" onclick = "linx('https://link.com/', 1)">Some text here</p>
```

in css:

```
.disabled {
cursor: auto;
pointer-events: none;
  opacity: 0;
}

.actv .disabled{
cursor: pointer;
    pointer-events: auto;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: 0.2s;
}
```

And in javascript (part with the button supposed to make button inactive after link is pressed (also doesn't work at the moment)):

```
function linx(url, x){
btns = document.getElementsByTagName("BUTTON");
if (btns.item(x).classList.contains("actv")){
btns.item(x).classList.remove("actv");
btns.item(x).value = 0;
btns.item(x).blur();
window.open(url, '_blank').focus();
}else{
    return;
}
```

}

It works exactly right on androind and PC, but on iPad with Chrome I can either make link clickable when it is BOTH visible and hidden or unclickable when it is both visible and hidden.

I've searched most actual topics with similar questions, and tried different methods (changing cursor type, changing pointer-events type, adding touch-action etc), nothing helped.

Also changing display:none; display:inherit did not help either.